# Phase shift in an active RC shifter

Tags: operational-amplifier, phase-shift

How can I find the phase shift as a function of \$R_1\$? I found online that the equation is \$\phi = −2\arctan(R_1/X_c)\$, I just can't figure out why the 2 is there.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0pmKb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Link to the on-line site that gave you that equation please. You have also drawn an op-amp so now you need to be clear about which output you are concerning yourself with regards the phase shift.

Comment: Did you try to derive the transfer function assuming the op-amp output is where the response is observed? You can apply superposition to this circuit with \$V_{in}\$ applied to \$R_1\$ and \$R_3\$ or use the FACTs. There is one pole and one zero.

Comment: This is a LPF converted to an "All-Pass" phase shift (with unity inverting gain). So the RC phase shift between 0 and 90 is doubled as it transitions between  0 towards inverting 180 deg for rising f. The Vpp remains unchanged.  Use transfer functions to solve.

Answer (score 4):

With a circuit like this one, there are two options: the brute-force approach or the FACTs. For the first one, you can apply the superposition theorem with the input voltage alternatively biasing \$R_1\$ and \$R_3\$ or use the more mathematical KVL-/KCL-based approached described by Jan in his answer.

The second approach that I favor most of the time consists of determining the time constant of this circuit as described by the fast analytical circuits techniques or FACTs. As described in my [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1119236371) on the subject, the principle is simple: determine the time constant involving \$C_1\$ when the excitation is reduced to 0 V (\$V_{in}\$ is replaced by a short circuit) and when the response is *nulled*. We can start by setting \$s\$ to 0 (dc gain) and see what gain does this circuit exhibit. The below drawing shows the step for this dc analysis. If you do the maths ok (via superposition for instance), you find a gain of 1 regardless of the resistors values:

[image]

You then carry on with turning the source off and determining the resistance "seen" from \$C_1\$ terminals. It's easy in this case as it is \$R_1\$ and you have \$\tau_1=R_1C_1\$. Because with a 1st-order circuit the pole is the inverse of the time constant. The pole position is immediate and equal to \$\omega_p=\frac{1}{R_1C_1}\$. For the zero, either you determine the value of \$R\$ when the output is a null or you determine the gain of the circuit at high frequency e.g. when \$C_1\$ is replaced by a short circuit: \$H^1=-\frac{R_4}{R_3}\$. Applying this result by following the guidelines you have a zero located at \$\omega_z=-\frac{R_3}{R_4R_1C_1}\$ and this is a right-half-plane zero (RHPZ).

Since the pole and the zero are located at the same position, they neutralize each other in magnitude and the overall gain is 1 (0 dB) along the frequency axis. However, because of the zero located in the right half-plane, its phase response lags rather than leading as with a classical LHP zero. As a result, it combines with the naturally-lagging response of the pole and brings the phase from 0° down to -180°:

[image]

Because \$R_3\$ and \$R_4\$ are of equal values, the pole and the zero solely depend on \$R_1\$ and \$C_1\$. Considering a negative zero, the phase of the expression is thus classically computed as:

[image]

This is an all-pass filter which creates a delay whose value depends on the value of \$R_1\$ and \$C_1\$. If you push the maths a little more, this is a way to create a 1st-order Padé approximant of \$e^{-sT}\$ which is a pure delay.

Answer (score 2):

> First, I will present a method that uses [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica) to solve this problem. When I was studying this stuff I used the method all the time (without using Mathematica of course).

Well, we are trying to analyze the following [opamp-circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsTWRS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff%27s_current_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_\text{i}=\text{I}_1+\text{I}_3\\
\\
\text{I}_1=\text{I}_2\\
\\
0=\text{I}_3+\text{I}_4\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\text{I}_\text{i}+\text{I}_4
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_4=\frac{\text{V}_3-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_4}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Substitute \$(2)\$ into \$(1)\$, in order to get:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_\text{i}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_1}+\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_1}=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
0=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_3}+\frac{\text{V}_3-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_2}=\text{I}_\text{i}+\frac{\text{V}_3-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_4}
\end{cases}\tag3
$$

Now, using an [ideal opamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier#Ideal_op_amps), we know that:

$$\text{V}_x:=\text{V}_+=\text{V}_-=\text{V}_1=\text{V}_2\tag4$$

So we can rewrite equation \$(3)\$ as follows:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_\text{i}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_x}{\text{R}_1}+\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_x}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_x}{\text{R}_1}=\frac{\text{V}_x}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
0=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_x}{\text{R}_3}+\frac{\text{V}_3-\text{V}_x}{\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_x}{\text{R}_2}=\text{I}_\text{i}+\frac{\text{V}_3-\text{V}_x}{\text{R}_4}
\end{cases}\tag5
$$

Now, we can solve for the transfer function:

$$\mathcal{H}:=\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{V}_\text{i}}=\frac{\text{R}_2\text{R}_3-\text{R}_1\text{R}_4}{\text{R}_3\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2\right)}\tag6$$

Where I used the following Mathematica-code:

```
In[1]:=Clear["Global`*"];
V1 = Vx;
V2 = Vx;
FullSimplify[
 Solve[{Ii == I1 + I3, I1 == I2, 0 == I3 + I4, I2 == Ii + I4, 
   I1 == (Vi - V2)/R1, I2 == V2/R2, I3 == (Vi - V1)/R3, 
   I4 == (V3 - V1)/R4}, {Ii, I1, I2, I3, I4, Vx, V3}]]

Out[1]={{Ii -> ((R1 + R3) Vi)/((R1 + R2) R3), I1 -> Vi/(R1 + R2), 
  I2 -> Vi/(R1 + R2), I3 -> (R1 Vi)/((R1 + R2) R3), 
  I4 -> -((R1 Vi)/((R1 + R2) R3)), Vx -> (R2 Vi)/(R1 + R2), 
  V3 -> ((R2 R3 - R1 R4) Vi)/((R1 + R2) R3)}}
```

My equation was also confirmed using [LTspice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LTspice).

---

When we want to apply the derivation from above to your circuit we need to use [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform) (I will use lower case function names for the functions that are in the (complex) s-domain, so \$\text{y}\left(\text{s}\right)\$ is the Laplace transform of the function \$\text{Y}\left(t\right)\$):

$$\text{R}_2=\frac{1}{\text{sC}}\tag7$$

So, we can rewrite the transfer function as:

$$\mathscr{H}\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{\frac{1}{\text{sC}}\cdot\text{R}_3-\text{R}_1\text{R}_4}{\text{R}_3\left(\text{R}_1+\frac{1}{\text{sC}}\right)}=\frac{\text{R}_3-\text{sCR}_1\text{R}_4}{\text{R}_3\left(1+\text{sCR}_1\right)}\tag8$$

Now, when working with sinusoidal signals we can use \$\text{s}:=\text{j}\omega\$ (where \$\text{j}^2=-1\$ and \$\omega=2\pi\text{f}\$ with \$\text{f}\$ is the frequency of the input signal in Hertz). So we get:

$$\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)=\frac{\text{R}_3-\omega\text{CR}_1\text{R}_4\text{j}}{\text{R}_3\left(1+\omega\text{CR}_1\text{j}\right)}\tag9$$

Now, you want to find the argument:

$$\arg\left(\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right)=\arg\left(\frac{\text{R}_3-\omega\text{CR}_1\text{R}_4\text{j}}{\text{R}_3\left(1+\omega\text{CR}_1\text{j}\right)}\right)=$$
$$\arg\left(\text{R}_3-\omega\text{CR}_1\text{R}_4\text{j}\right)-\arg\left(\text{R}_3\left(1+\omega\text{CR}_1\text{j}\right)\right)=$$
$$\arg\left(\text{R}_3-\omega\text{CR}_1\text{R}_4\text{j}\right)-\left(\arg\left(\text{R}_3\right)+\arg\left(1+\omega\text{CR}_1\text{j}\right)\right)=$$
$$\frac{3\pi}{2}+\arctan\left(\frac{\text{R}_3}{\omega\text{CR}_1\text{R}_4}\right)-\left(0+\arctan\left(\frac{\omega\text{CR}_1}{1}\right)\right)=$$
$$\frac{3\pi}{2}+\arctan\left(\frac{\text{R}_3}{\omega\text{CR}_1\text{R}_4}\right)-\arctan\left(\omega\text{CR}_1\right)\tag{10}$$

> Now, when \$\text{R}_3=\text{R}_4\$ (which is the case in your circuit) we can simplify it a bit:
>
> $$\arg\left(\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right)=\frac{3\pi}{2}+\arctan\left(\frac{1}{\omega\text{CR}_1}\right)-\arctan\left(\omega\text{CR}_1\right)=$$
> $$2\left(\pi-\arctan\left(\omega\text{CR}_1\right)\right)\tag{11}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**

Using superposition, the transfer function (first order allpass, special case **R3=R4**) is

**H(s)**=[1/(1+sR1C1)]*[1+1]-1=[2-(1+sR1C1)] / (1+sR1C1)=**(1-sR1C1) / (1+sR1C1)** .

**Phi**=Phi_n - phi_d = arctan(-wR1C1) - artan(wR1C1) = **-2arctan(wR1C1)**.